# Colab Jupyter notebook doesn't recognize functions after correct module import of fastai.vision

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I worked quite a while on my .ipynb file on `Colab`. I'm working with `fastai(v.2)`, yesterday I unintentionally tried to use `open_image` function from `fastai(v.1)`, which wasn't recognized - no surprise. After restarting the runtime I got `NameErrors` on every `fastai(also v2)` function used in the whole code.

To fix this I:

- restarted runtime
- closed all running sessions
- imported every module by name although the import functions worked fine before
- restarted computer
- tried on a different computer
- started a new notebook

Once in a while it works on another notebook, but as soon as I run the original one I get the Name errors on every notebook I use.

Minimal code I used to reproduce the error myself is here. But since I guess it's a bug of my `colab` it'll be hard to reproduce. Anyway if somebody has got an idea let me know!

```html
!pip install -Uqq fastai 
from fastai.vision.all import *
from scipy.io import loadmat 

print(fastai.__version__)

my_batch_tfms = aug_transforms(size=224)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a Colab bug which is Accound bound. I started the exact same code with another Google Account in Colab and everything worked perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code here

```
from fastai.vision import *
```

To

```
from fastai.vision.all import *
```

Comment: from fastai.vision.all import * ist correct of course - but error is the same since I used fastai.vision.all in the original file where the error occured